# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'convertDocxToText'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am converting `docx` files to `text` files to read content in the files for further processing. While doing so I was trying to use `convertDocxToText` function. But it is throwing a `ModuleNotFoundError`. How do I resolve this error?

```
extension = fileName.split(".")[-1]     
if extension == "docx":  
    return convertDocxToText(fileName), extension
```

Comment: You are getting [ModuleNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError) because you may have forgotten to import a dependent module. If your `ModuleNotFoundError` function is depending on another module that is not built-in you will have to import it explicitly.

Comment: I am unable to find the dependent module itself that I need to import. What is the best way to find the dependent module? I am working with Python 3.6.

Comment: Can you post the complete code here ? at least the function code.

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/divapriya/Language_Processing/blob/master/convertDocxToText.py) should help you

Comment: I was assuming that python might have a convertor. I found https://pypi.org/project/docx2txt/ useful to convert docs to text. Thanks.